# How can I open an mp3 file on Android using MediaPlayer, knowing the file path?

Tags: android, path, uri, android-mediaplayer, mp3

I want an application that has a background music, selected by the user, using a browse button. After i have the "path" to the file, I can't make it to play, my mPlayer is always null.
My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, 
     Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/mymusic.mp3"));

    mPlayer.start();
}
```

}